# How to display image in asp.net from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to display image from folder in asp.net datalist control. I have written following code but getting full path of file name.
here my code is

//HTML element

```
<asp:DataList CssClass= ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="image-container">
            <div class="image">
             <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
            </div>
            <div class="file-name">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

//Code Behind

```
 public void displayimage ()

    {

        string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images"));
        List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());



        foreach (string items in filesindirectory)
        {
            images.Add(String.Format("~/images/{0}", Path.GetFileName(items)));
        }



        PagedDataSource obj = new PagedDataSource();
        obj.DataSource = images;
        obj.AllowPaging = true;
        obj.PageSize = 5;
        obj.CurrentPageIndex = currentpage;
        Label4.Text = "Page : " + (currentpage + 1).ToString() + " of " + obj.PageCount.ToString();
        Btn_Previous.Enabled = !obj.IsFirstPage;
        Btn_next.Enabled = !obj.IsLastPage;
        DataList1.DataSource = obj;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Please help

Comment: How is the css class `image` defined? Are you somehow hiding the div?

Comment: sometimes it may be a problem with image itself. Did you try opening images directly with browsers? If images were not created for web, they won't appear in browser.

Comment: `CssClass= ID="DataList1" ` <-- is that a typo ?